# How to edit top link navgation in sharePoint 2016?

Tags: sharepoint-online, top-link-bar, top-navigation

Hello I can't seem to edit top link navgation menu bar. 
[image]

I can't seem to re-name /sites/rms it don't allow me to chage in nvagation setting.

Is there anyway I can change it.

kind regards,
Anees

Answer (score 1):

Check if the Web has Title in Site Settings, the first link is always to "this web".

Comment: There is no title it is blank .

Comment: You can add the Name on title section in site setting then it will take few mins to get it reflect in your home page..

Comment: Yes, it was the reason, there must be some title :) Mark it as aswer, thanks.